# How to change Color of ModelRenderable?

Tags: android, colors, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

i have a ModelRenderable attached to a Node and rendered in an ArFragment.

I would like to highlight this element to the user for 0.5 sec in a prominent color.

I tried to change the material, but it didn't work out. The rendering freezes without throwing an error. Here is what I tried:

```
private void addHighlightToNode(Node node) {

    CompletableFuture<Material> materialCompletableFuture =
            MaterialFactory.makeOpaqueWithColor(this, new Color(0, 255, 244));
    ModelRenderable highlightedRenderable = (ModelRenderable) node.getRenderable();
    highlightedRenderable = highlightedRenderable.makeCopy();
    try {
        highlightedRenderable.setMaterial(materialCompletableFuture.get());
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    node.setRenderable(highlightedRenderable);
}
```

I managed to set the light of the Node to a different color in runtime, but the effect is not close to what I need.

```
node.setLight(Light.builder(Light.Type.POINT).setColor(new Color(0,255,244)).build());
```

How can I change the color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating the material is asynchronous, that's why it returns a CompletableFuture.  You are calling CompletableFuture.get(), which is a blocking call, but since you are on the UI thread it ends up freezing the app.
If you move the setting to be called in thenAccept, it works correctly.

```
  private void addHighlightToNode(Node node) {
    CompletableFuture<Material> materialCompletableFuture =
            MaterialFactory.makeOpaqueWithColor(this, new Color(0, 255, 244));

    materialCompletableFuture.thenAccept(material -> {
      Renderable r2 = node.getRenderable().makeCopy();
      r2.setMaterial(material);
      node.setRenderable(r2);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Well, thank you! That solved the problem and I learned more about what I'm actually doing here...

Comment: You can also change the color of an existing material like this:

material.setFloat3(MaterialFactory.MATERIAL_COLOR, new Color(0, 1.0f, 0.9f);

Different materials have different material parameters, the material from makeOpaqueWithColor has a float3 color parameter, documented [here](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/sceneform/rendering/MaterialFactory.html#MATERIAL_COLOR)