# ArCore set transparency of nodes and restore state

Tags: android, transparency, arcore

I am working on an app with ArCore. I need set model transparent in time of moving, and after the changing position restore color and opacity.
I've found how to [make transparency of model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51405596/how-to-change-color-of-modelrenderable), but after that - animation of model have been lost:(. And it is not returning...
And I can't restore base color and opacity. If somebody help, you are will be my Hero)

```
 private void addHighlightToNode(Node node) {
    CompletableFuture<Material> materialCompletableFuture =
            MaterialFactory.makeTransparentWithColor(getAppContext(), new Color(getAppContext().getColor(R.color.colorTransparent)));
    materialCompletableFuture.thenAccept(material -> {
        Renderable r2 = node.getRenderable().makeCopy();
        r2.setMaterial(material);
        node.setRenderable(r2);
    });
}
```